# Stack Exchange like application for Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, app

Stack Exchange sites function pretty well. Is there something like this available for SharePoint 2013?

I'm looking for some QA/KB application which could be integrated with on-premises installation of SP2013.

Answer (score 1):

Community Sites do exactly this.